# Nginx: config set up to make extensionless php pages work

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to set up my first website with nginx and I cannot seem to make extensionless php pages to work.
I would like my pages like /aboutme.php to appear as /aboutme **or** I would like to just change my URLs to /aboutme instead of /aboutme.php and make those work.
I managed to make the last scenario work on cpanel hosting by editing .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

However, if I convert htaccess code to nginx using online tools, it doesn't work. I also tried to edit my nginx.conf with try_files and extensionless-php with no success, I get 404. My plain nginx.conf without try_files and extensionless-php looks like this:

```
server {
listen   localhost:8081; 
server_name mywebsite.com; # I use my website here
root /usr/share/nginx/web/website1;
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/web/website1;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  }
location ~ \.php$ {
      root           /usr/share/nginx/web/website1;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Edit: my question got marked as a duplicate elsewhere, so I tried to configure it as it was said with no success, if I visit '/aboutme' I get '404 not found', if I visit '/aboutme.php', it's opened as '/aboutme.php' with '.php':

```
server {
listen       localhost:8081;
server_name  mywebsite.com;
root         /usr/share/nginx/web/website1;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
}
```

error log: 2018/03/14 14:39:32 [error] 7714#7714: *27 open() "/usr/share/nginx/web/website1/aboutme" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /about HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "mywebsite.com/"; there is aboutme.php present in directory, nginx version 1.10.3
I tried restarting nginx and vps multiple times.